# Fastest alternative to rbind.fill

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, rbind

What is the fastest alternative to rbind.fill? I have a list of dataframes (all with the same column names) and would like to create one big dataframe that has used `rbind` on each dataframe (or something equivalent to this). Any solution, including `tidyverse` is good.

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(x)`, `data.table::rbindlist(x)`, base `do.call(rbind, x)` are all very fast, *much* faster than `rbind`ing one frame at a time (which is the second circle within the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), *"Growing Objects"*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a speed comparison performed of `rbind`, `bind_rows`, and `rbindlist` by Ashwin Malshé in 2018 https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/406521_7fc7b6c1dc374e9b8860e15a699d8bb0.html

In ascending order:

1. `rbindlist` from `data.table` is the fastest. It’s more than twice faster than `bind_rows` from `dplyr`.
2. `bind_rows` from `dplyr`, which was more than 10 times faster than `rbind` from `base R`
3. `rbind` `base R`

There are certainly a few extreme values in all 3 simulations but the medians are close to the means, suggesting small influence of extreme values!

Answer (score -1):

If the data frames are in a list, the base R Reduce function can rbind them all. e.g.,

```
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- df1
df3 <- df2
mylist <- list(df1, df2, df3)
rbindall <- Reduce(rbind, mylist)
```

Comment: While the use of `Reduce` is admirable and relatively varsity in R circles, I dv'd this because it is actually the *slowest* option performance-wise (due to memory allocation and how `rbind.data.frame` works under the hood). By orders of magnitude, even with modest data. (I don't know of any reasonable method that is actually slower and less-efficient memory-wise. R is good at many things, this is not a good example of that :-). Good reprex answer, just an antipattern.